# how can wpf app get the standard output of every program it calls(a call b, b call c, a get c's standoutout)

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a wpf app A, it calls another program B, B will call another program C, how can I get C's standard output in A?
Currently I used

```
importer.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "pdms.bat");
importer.StartInfo.Arguments = GetImportParam();
importer.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
importer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
importer.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
importer.Start();
string str = importer.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

importer.WaitForExit();
importer.Close();
```

The code can read B's standard output, but it can't read C's.

Comment: What is A-B-C? is it a function? If these are functions, could you add those functions to the problem? It is useful to make the problem more understandable or it may be closed.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me! Yes they are functions, they are like a call chain, but the wpf app can only get the standard output of the  function it calls directly.